# CHAR_USED query returned '0 rows fetched from 1 column'

Tags: oracle

I created the following table:

```
Create table temp.test(c1 VARCHAR2(10 BYTE));
```

I was trying to use CHAR_USED to determine whether the column size is in BYTES or CHARS but all I am getting back is '0 rows fetched from 1 column'. The database version i am using is Oracle 11g. Does anyone have a clue as to why it is not return the semantic length information for this table?

The query used are as follows:

```
select CHAR_USED from all_tab_columns where table_name='temp.test'
select CHAR_USED from all_tab_columns where table_name='test' and owner = 'temp'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are not using case-sensitive identifiers (which you are not and should not), object names are stored in the data dictionary in upper case.  So when you query a table like `all_tab_columns`, you'd need to use upper-case

```
SELECT column_name, char_used
  FROM all_tab_columns
 WHERE table_name = 'TEST'
   AND owner = 'TEMP'
```